# Silverlight 4 application connecting to WCF Service fails

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, wcf

Been working on a Silverlight application which connects to a WCF Service on our server. I am using .NET 4.0 for development. Everything works fine locally, but I tried deploying the WCF Service on our server and it does not work.

The service is running fine, I checked by entering the URL in the browser. But whenever I make a call from my Silverlight application it fails with the error:

**System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.**

The detailed error is given below with my Web.Config file. I used fiddler to check the messages and I could see the response from the server contains the text.

**a:FailedAuthentication. Access Denied.**

What can I do to solve this? The problem is that my hosting server does not allow Windows Authentication to be turned on in IIS. Could not find the settings for that. I am using godaddy windows hosting.

Any pointers?

Web.Config:

```
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/></system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"></serviceHostingEnvironment>    
<services>
  <service name="WarpArtOnline.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WarpArtOnline.Service1Behavior">
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MaxSizeBinding" contract="WarpArtOnline.IService1">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <!--<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>-->
  </service>
</services>

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MaxSizeBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None">
        <!--<transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>-->
        <!--<transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />-->
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>


    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="WarpArtOnline.Service1Behavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Error:

`` {System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c_DisplayClass5.b_4(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c_DisplayClass4.b_1(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase1.ChannelBase1.EndInvoke(String methodName, Object[] args, IAsyncResult result)
   at ImagingSL.WebWarp.Service1Client.Service1ClientChannel.EndwarpImage(IAsyncResult result)
   at ImagingSL.WebWarp.Service1Client.ImagingSL.WebWarp.IService1.EndwarpImage(IAsyncResult result)
   at ImagingSL.WebWarp.Service1Client.OnEndwarpImage(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.OnAsyncCallCompleted(IAsyncResult result)} ``

Comment: Hmm using Windows Authentication over the Internet. What category of users is supposed to work with that service?

Comment: The service should be accessible to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Have you modified the **clientaccesspolicy.xml** file? You need to enable cross domain access in this file.Refer to this
[Making a Service Available Across Domain Boundaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Nothing in his post indicates a crossdomain issue.

Comment: I have a clientaccesspolicy.xml at the root of my domain and it is not an issue with that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file in your Silverlight project?  If so have you checked all the endpoint settings?

Comment: The trouble is that particular error "NotFound" can mean just about anything. It is just a generic error message that WCF uses to say something failed.  Have you tried enabling WCF tracing (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx).  It may provide more clues to you.

Comment: P.S Do you know how the WCF services are configured on IIS?  Are they set up for anonymous access?

Comment: Just noticed you still have authenticationMode=Windows in your web.config.  If the services are to be accessible to everyone you will need to change this to authenticationMode=None.

Comment: Hi guys, the problem is that the wcf service on the web server runs in a environment with medium trust level. My WCF service contains code that requires full trust. I contacted the support staff and they were not able to help me since I am on shared hosting.